# Get DialogResult from custom dialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some custom made dialog that have on it Set Button , I want when i exit from `newBlockForm.ShowDialog(this);` to get the dialog result if the user pressed on that button or not .

Like i would do in winforms dialog

```
if(MessageBox.Show("Exit?", "Close UP", 
     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)== DialogResult.Yes)
```

Any idea how i do so ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx) Property of the Button on your Dialog form and set it to [DialogResult Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) like:

```
//in your dialog form
button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

then in your main form :

```
//Create an instance of your dialog form
Form2 testDialog = new Form2();

// Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
if (testDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
   //do processing
}
else
{
   //do processing
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Map the `AcceptButton` property on the Form to `Set` button in the designer.

Or in the Set button click handler you could set some value.

```
        private void HandleOnSetButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.IsSetClicked = true;
            this.Close();

            //or 
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }   

        public Boolean IsSetClicked
        {
           get;
           private set;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog` method returns a `DialogResult` by itself which you can set automatically by setting the `DialogResult` of the buttons in question in your form designer.